# Select DataFrame data base on series value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean, series

I have a pandas' DataFrame and when I perform an operation on the dataframe, I get back a series.  How can I use that series to select out only records where I find a match?

Right now I'm appending the column onto the DataFrame and doing a query against the dataframe then dropping the column.  I really do not like this solution though, so I'm hoping I can get a better solution.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4], [3,4,5]]
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
series = df.myoperation()
df['myoperation'] = series
res = df[df['myoperation'] == True] 
del res['myoperation']
```

The `series` object will produce a 1-1 match, so index item 1 will match item 1 in the dataframe object.

Above is my hacky code to get it done, but I'm afraid when the dataframe have many column or a lot more data than just this simple example, it will be slow.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use if `series` is boolean `Series` with same index as `df` and same length as `df` - it is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
series = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=df.index)
res = df[series]
print (res)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  3  4  5
```

It always works with `boolean` list and numpy array, only lenght has to be same as `df`:

```
L = [True, False, True]
res = df[L]
print (res)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  3  4  5
```

---

```
arr = np.array([True, False, True])
res = df[arr]
print (res)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
2  3  4  5
```